# Please tell most common short cuts keys of the blender?

Tags: shortcut

Please help and tell the most commonly used keyboard shortcuts keys for blender.

Comment: This question is very broad. What specific keyboard shortcut are you looking for?

Comment: [infographic](https://steamuserimages-a.akamaihd.net/ugc/308866001608881149/7BC9BD057191B43B8A0E98E79D3CDCF593F7A9D8/)

Comment: @Dan You should post that as an answer - that’s fantastic.

Comment: @RichSedman Done, but i'm emberassed of this kind of "answer" :)

Comment: Please read number 7 on this link: [What questions should be definitely off-topic?](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6/1853)

Answer (score 4):

As said this is too broad and too dependent on what **you** mean by most commonly used, in your blender usage.

Anyway you can find the shortcut alongside the command in every menu

[image]

or in the command search function (<kbd>Space</kbd>)

[image]

or the full list in the user preference window

[image]

where you can even delete, change add them and even create your own custom set (or use one of the predefined ones)

Answer (score 4):

Here you have a very helpful [Info graphic](https://bcgiu.wordpress.com/2015/02/12/best-blender-key-map-infographic/) by giudansky.com

*website seems to be down, so i linked it from https://bcgiu.wordpress.com*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what are you using Blender for.
If you are absolute beginner, I suggest you to watch some YouTube tutorials, I especially like Andrew Price alias BlenderGuru and his beginner series, I am sure you are able to find it yourself.

Then if you want a pure shortcuts overview, I can add a link the official documentation (it is for an older Blender version but they are the same for the current one).
https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Reference/Hotkeys/All